# Weird choppy video on my new UHD monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card, refresh-rate

Hopefully this is the right place to ask this:

I just bought a 32" UHD monitor (from [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Perfect-Pixel-CrossOver-324K-UHD-32-3840x2160-60Hz-2-0-HDMI-DP-Monitor-Remote-/331754747611?hash=item4d3e1fb6db:g:5aYAAOSw6dNWTWa7)), and a new graphics card (an NVidia GT 730, [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127830&cm_re=MSI_GeForce_GT_730_DirectX_12_N730K-1GD5LP%2fOC_1GB_64-Bit_GDDR5_PCI_Express_2.0_x16_HDCP_Ready_Low_Profile_Video_Card-_-14-127-830-_-Product)) to drive it. The resulting picture is gorgeous, everything looks really nice. However, the images on the screen are sometimes noticeably slow to update. I can tell sometimes as I move my mouse and its movement becomes choppy, but it's especially apparent when watching full-screen HD video. Something like a large object sliding across the screen can cause weird choppy lines, etc.

I'm running Linux (NixOS) on a machine with a Core i7-2600 CPU (3.40GHz) and 16GB of RAM. I'm using the NVidia linux drivers to drive the graphics card. I'm guessing that the cause of the choppiness is a low refresh rate, although I'm not sure. The monitor is listed as being able to do 60Hz, but in my settings, my graphics card seems to only be able to manage 30. Do I need a more powerful graphics card? Or is this likely a shortcoming of the monitor? Perhaps something else?

Comment: Have you tried using the intel HD graphics for a quick test? How are you connecting to the monitor (HDMI, DisplayPort..)?

Comment: How did you connect the monitor? For 60Hz you either need HDMI 2.0 or DisplayPort. I also don't know if the GT 730 is meant to drive a 4K monitor (that's a large amount of pixels being updated every frame).

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's the graphics card. Sigh. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your graphics card. From the [nvidia website](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-730/specifications), in the very fine print:

> 3840x2160 at 30Hz or 4096x2160 at 24Hz supported over HDMI. 3840x2160
>   at 60Hz supported over DisplayPort